# Div sliding down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Well, this is actually a complicated problem, the default behavior of a header is simple, it gets in front of everything, however I want to put a div that will overlap it, putting a blur on the page, my goal is for the header to be behind of this div.

```css
.body{
min-height: 2000px;
}

.overlay{
    background-color: rgba(126, 246, 53, 0.50);
    z-index: 1050;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

.overlayDiv{
    background: white;
    z-index: 1051;
    margin-top: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Header</a>
</nav>
  
<div class="body">

<div class="overlayDiv col-8 offset-2">
  <h1>That's divs on top of the page</h1>
</div>

<div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
```

As you can see in the example, `overlayDiv` is above the `overlay`, which is what I want, but it goes over the menu, what I want is for the menu to be over it even being opaque, would that be possible?

Edit:

I would like to do something rather complicated, I will explain otherwise to try to clarify.

The top div has to go under the header when it gets there, and fade in behind it partially.

so it looks like it's entering the page just below the header,
I thought of going to cut the height of her, but the content is not getting the way desired, example: cutting the text

Edit 2.0:

The div of the text displayed in the example really has to be above the mask, and the menu below the mask.

The idea is that as div reaches the height of the menu it slowly moves past it, as if sliding down the menu

would look something like this

[image]

Comment: simply make the z-index of the menu bigger

Comment: This was explained in the question, I do not want the menu to be over this green div, but it has to stay above the text div

Comment: not 100% sure what you want: <nav> should be on top of everything but one other div should lay one zindex level above to put some more "style" on it? or should the nav be untouched by the overlaying div?

Comment: in the title you said *a div do not overlap the header* then you said  *my goal is for the header to be behind of this div.* then again *I want is for the menu to be over it even being opaque,* ... you need to be clear on what you want (either behind or above)

Comment: I think you're better off understanding the title now.

Comment: any idea? haven't figured out how to do it yet

Comment: You mean you want your div to slide out from between header and body?

Comment: exactly. but I do not know how

Comment: It is still not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Paranhos Please check below is it something you want !

Comment: This was explained in the question, I do not want the menu to be over this green div, but it has to stay above the text div

@Paranhos According to this statement i have made some changes in answer, please check.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help but I already managed to solve the problem

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Based on your answers I was able to think of a solution that was plausible to solve the problem, thank you for your commitment, what I needed is below

```css
.body{
min-height: 2000px;
}

.overlay{
    background-color: rgba(126, 246, 53, 0.50);
    z-index: 1028;
    position: absolute;
    height: 2000px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

.overlayDiv{
    background: white;
    z-index: 1029;
    margin-top: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.navOverlayDiv{
    background-color: rgba(126, 246, 53, 0.50);
    z-index: 1053;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Header</a>
<div class="navOverlayDiv">
</div>
</nav>
  
<div class="body">

<div class="overlayDiv col-8 offset-2">
  <h1>That's divs on top of the page</h1>
</div>

<div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Read about downsides of using !important is CSS first and after comeback!

Comment: the! important was used because I can't include the snipet css after the bootstrap css, so I either put the! important or a style tag inside the code, and both are bad practice

Comment: you can use nested selectors like: `.body .overlay {...}`

Comment: i think you can use `background` to `header` rather than using important, it will work either way !

Comment: I sincerely would like to understand why so much downvote being an answer to my own question and none of the others works the way you ask

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, you want the navbar between `overlayDiv` and `overlay`? You can do this by adjusting the `z-index`es. `navbar` gets a default `z-index` of `1030`, so set `overlayDiv`'s `z-index` to something higher, and `overlay`'s to something lower:

```css
.body{
  min-height: 2000px;
  z-index: 99;
}

.overlay{
  background-color: rgba(126, 246, 53, 0.50);
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 97;
}

.overlayDiv{
  background: white;
  z-index: 5000;
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 98;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Header</a>
</nav>
  
<div class="body">

<div class="overlayDiv col-8 offset-2">
  <h1>That's divs on top of the page</h1>
</div>

<div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
```

**Edit:** z-index is the right way of usage in this particular case.

Comment: your text is still going above the header, please check.

Comment: I think that's what the OP is asking for.

Comment: No, because the header is above the mask, the idea is that it is below the mask but the menu still above the mask is below it, and yet the header is being overlaid by the text div, the idea is that it is not

Comment: @Lucas see the answer above again. Every element you put as overlay should include a z-index. This is the correct answer.

Comment: @Lucas here is a fiddle that would help you to understand: https://jsfiddle.net/BerkerYuceer/jm9crL8h/ 
also a link teaches how:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: but I already said that was not what I wanted, it is very clear in the problem

Comment: there is a picture that shows what you want, which you can see in only two of the answers

Answer (score 2):

Please check is it something you want i guess.

```css
.body{
min-height: 2000px;
}
nav.fixed-top{
z-index: 1050;
background: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.overlay{
    background-color: rgba(126, 246, 53, 0.50);
    z-index: 1060;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

.overlayDiv{
    background: white;
    z-index:1040;
    margin-top: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Header</a>
</nav>
  
<div class="body">

<div class="overlayDiv col-8 offset-2">
  <h1>That's divs on top of the page</h1>
</div>

<div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: No, because the div is under the mask, the idea is that it is above the mask but not above the menu

Comment: This was explained in the question, I do not want the menu to be over this green div, but it has to stay above the text div.

you explained here green should be over the menu, but text shouldn't be over the menu, that is what i have done. 

But i think you need it like text div should be over the green but not above the header, Green area will be above the header right ? In that case we might need need to introduce some js or we have to make it in `:after`, let me know.

Comment: I tried javascript, decreasing the div's height as it was at the top of the page, but this resulted in an event being triggered all the time and not being effective because the text was shifting. but if you have a javascript solution it is acceptable

Comment: and the use of the pseudo element: after doesn't work because in this element of mine in real use I have a form

Answer (score 1):

Simply add  `<div class="BlurDiv"> </div>`

Place the div around the entire html, so whatever your top container div is for example if it was `<div class="main-container"></div>`

Make it like this:

```
<div class="BlurDiv">
  <div class="main-container">
  </div>
</div>
```

then create your blur CSS and assign it to div id BlurDiv.

Answer (score 0):

There is one other solution i found bit tricky but meet requirement, i am adding a same `background` to `nav` as `overlay`. Now it will show white background on text as well as getting under 'nav'. This will also allow you to click on `nav` elements.

```css
.body {
  min-height: 2000px;
}

nav.fixed-top {
  z-index: 1080;
  background: #befa99;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.overlay {
  background-color: rgba(126, 246, 53, 0.50);
  z-index: 1030;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.overlayDiv {
  background: white;
  z-index: 1040;
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Header</a>
</nav>

<div class="body">
  <div class="overlayDiv col-8 offset-2">
    <h1>That's divs on top of the page</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```